# Get money from USA to India

Tags: united-states, india, payment

I am a freelancer and need to get payment from a client living in USA. 
I am in India.

I am using paypal and they charge a lot of fees and I hate to use them.

What are the alternative to get commercial payment in India?

I tried xoom.com but they do not allow my client to send commercial payment.

My client is American and I am Indian.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways; each has its own pro's and con's

SWIFT:
Fast reliable payment.
Higher Charges.
If payments are large and routine the charges can be less

Remittance Service:
Ideal for person to person transfer. Can be used by Companies to transfer to Individuals.
Less Faster compared to SWIFT. Quite Cheaper compared to SWIFT

Check's:
Long time is getting it cleared in India. Typically around month.
Quite Cheap. Almost NIL charges.